# why is tensorflow.map_fn slow, what is wrong with following code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use tensorflow map_fn to do parallel computation. However it seems to me that the performance gain is not significant.

Here are example code running Python 3.6.5, Tensorflow version 1.12.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 28 duo cores (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @ 2.60GHz) = 56 processors

These same codes running on Amazon AWS SagerMaker ml-p3-xlarge even took longer time, 227 seconds.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time
# version 1
tic = time.time()
elems = np.array(range(1,1000000), dtype=np.float64)
output = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x**6 , elems, dtype=tf.float64,  parallel_iterations=56)
sess = tf.Session()

res = sess.run(output)
toc = time.time() - tic
print("elapsed=", toc)  # 29.47 (seconds)

# version 2
tic = time.time()
elems = np.array(range(1,1000000), dtype=np.float64)
output = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x**6 , elems, dtype=tf.float64,   parallel_iterations=56)
n_cpus=28


with  tf.Session(
config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True, 
device_count={ "CPU": n_cpus },
inter_op_parallelism_threads=n_cpus,
intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
```

)) as sess:
    res = sess.run(output)

```
toc = time.time() - tic
print("elapsed=", toc)  # 29.26 (seconds)

# version 3
tic = time.time()
elems = np.array(range(1,1000000), dtype=np.float64)
x6 = [ x**6 for x in elems]
toc = time.time() - tic
print("elapsed time=", toc) # 0.5 seconds
```

What is problem with the above codes? without map_fn, sequential execution version 3 only 0.5 (seconds).

Comment: maybe the workload is not enough to see the benefits of parallelization?